# Проблема при записи в сессию

Tags: php

Есть сессия, в которую необходимо добавить значения по условию. Если ключ существует,то добавить к текущему ключу значение, если его не существует то, создать пару ключ и значение.

```
foreach($_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'] as $secId => $val)
{
    if($secId == $curSecId)
    {
        $checkSection = true;
        break;
    }
}

if( $checkSection )
{
    $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'][$curSecId][] = $prodId;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'] = ["{$curSecId}" => $prodId];
}
```

Проблема возникает, когда ключ есть. Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in . Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в `SECTIONS` хранятся пары ключ-значение, то так:

```
$_SESSION = [
    'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' => [
        'SECTIONS' => [
            'secId' => 'val'
        ]
    ]
];

$prodId = 'prodIt';

save('secId', $prodId);

var_export($_SESSION);
/*
array (
    'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' =>
    array (
      'SECTIONS' =>
      array (
        'secId' => 'prodIt',
      ),
    ),
  )
*/
save('new', $prodId);

var_export($_SESSION);
/*
array (
  'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' =>
  array (
    'SECTIONS' =>
    array (
      'new' => 'prodIt',
    ),
  ),
)
*/

function save($curSecId, $prodId) {
    $checkSection = false;
    foreach($_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'] as $secId => $val)
    {
        if($secId == $curSecId)
        {
            $checkSection = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $checkSection )
    {
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'][$curSecId] = $prodId;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'] = ["{$curSecId}" => $prodId];
    }
}
```

Если в `SECTION` хранятся ключи с массивом  значений, то так:

```
<?php

$_SESSION = [
    'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' => [
        'SECTIONS' => [
            'secId' => [
                'val'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$prodId = 'prodIt';

save('secId', $prodId);

var_export($_SESSION);
/*
array (
  'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' =>
  array (
    'SECTIONS' =>
    array (
      'secId' =>
      array (
        0 => 'val',
        1 => 'prodIt',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
*/
save('new', $prodId);

var_export($_SESSION);
/*
array (
  'PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED' =>
  array (
    'SECTIONS' =>
    array (
      'secId' =>
      array (
        0 => 'val',
        1 => 'prodIt',
      ),
      0 =>
      array (
        'new' =>
        array (
          0 => 'prodIt',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
*/

function save($curSecId, $prodId) {
    $checkSection = false;
    foreach($_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'] as $secId => $val)
    {
        if($secId == $curSecId)
        {
            $checkSection = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $checkSection )
    {
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'][$curSecId][] = $prodId;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTS_IN_COMPARED']['SECTIONS'][] = ["{$curSecId}" => [$prodId]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код не решает проблему. Нужно не обнулять предыдущие значения, а добавлять к текщим

Comment: Добавил решение для этой ситуации. Тогда нужно уточнить, что хранится в `SECTIONS`. Пары ключ-значение или ключи с массивом значений

Comment: спасибо,оказалось всё достаточно просто